# SQL make a list of not existing objects

Tags: sql

I have following problem. 
Two tables. Product Table and Inventory Table.

In Product table are a list of all possible products and in Inventory the current stock of each store

e.g. 
Inventory Table

```
ProductID     Stock     StoreID
1             10        1
2             10        1
3             10        1
1             10        2
```

Product Table

```
ProductID     Product     
1             Bananas        
2             Apples 
3             Oranges
4             Kiwi
```

What I want is a list of products that are not in stock for the stores.
Following the example the desired result would be

```
Store ProductID  Product
1     4          Kiwi 
2     2          Apples
2     3          Oranges 
2     4          Kiwi
```

Now I tried several approaches from left joins, not in and not exist but haven't found a solution. 
E.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Inventory t1 
left join Product t2 ON t2.ProductID = t1.ProductID 
WHERE t2.ProductID IS NULL
```

But this returns nothing

Any help please.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to your problem:

FOR **MySQL** as well as **MSSQL**

```
SELECT i.storeId,p.ProductId, p.product
FROM Product p
CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT Distinct storeId 
            FROM Inventory) i
LEFT JOIN Inventory iv
ON p.productID = iv.productId AND i.storeId = iv.storeId
WHERE iv.storeId IS NULL;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
storeId  ProductId  product
 1        4          Kiwi
 2        2          Apples
 2        3          Oranges
 2        4          Kiwi
```

Follow the link to the demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71a854/9

**CROSS JOIN:**

The `CROSS JOIN` produced a result set which is the product of rows of two associated tables when no WHERE clause is used with CROSS JOIN.

In this join, the result set appeared by multiplying each row of the first table with all rows in the second table if no condition introduced with CROSS JOIN.

This kind of result is called as Cartesian Product.

Below picture will give you a more clear picture:

[image]

Source:https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/mysql-cross-join.php

Comment: Dear Nishant, Thank you. That does the trick. I have never seen Cross Join. Would you mind explaining it to me a few words?

Comment: it solves the problem, and I learned something new. Thank you Nishant and Gordon

Comment: @PatrickJacob Welcome, if you find it useful please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should work, although selecting columns from only the first table makes sense.  And the first table should be the *product* table:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Product p LEFT JOIN
     Inventory i 
     ON i.ProductID = p.ProductID
WHERE i.ProductID IS NULL;
```

Your version returns all inventory products that are not in the `Product` table.  That should not be possible, if your data is correctly formatted.

Another way to write the query uses `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select p.*
from product p
where not exists (select 1 from inventory i where i.productid = p.productid);
```

This version (which should have very good performance if you have an index on `inventory(productid)`) comes closer to how you expressed the question.

Comment: Sorry, Gordon, I tried both suggested solutions and didn't get the desired result